# How to get max number in a column?

Tags: sql-server, coldfusion

I'm been trying to find a example of how to get a max number in a column.What I want to do is, find the MAX number of a column in a TABLE_A, points(column). I want to output this MAX number for example

```
<cfoutput>
    <tr>
    <th><div align="right">#maxnumber#</div></th>
    </tr>
    </cfoutput>
```

Not sure if this is the way to output, But I just want one number(the MAX) , not an array of the column.

thanks for your help, new to ColdFusion.

Comment: You're kinda asking two questions here: 1) how to use SQL to return the maximum value of table column; 2) how to output a value from a query. Both of these questions suggest to me perhaps you ought to be reading the docs a bit more rather than writing code (or not writing code, but asking for help in how to write code), just yet. These are very very fundamental questions, so you perhaps haven't done the minimum about of research/learning before commencing work. Here are the docs on outputting stuff from queries in CFML: https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/Outputting+query+data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this to get the top `X` from your query and then output them accordingly

```
<cfquery name="maxQuery">
SELECT TOP 2 points
FROM table_a
ORDER BY points DESC
</cfquery>

<cfoutput query="maxQuery">
  #maxQuery.currentRow# - #maxQuery.points#<br>
</cfoutput>
```

Answer (score 0):

sql have a max and min function to get the maximum and minimum values for a column.You can use max function to get it like below.

```
select max(point) from TABLE_A
```

Comment: sorry if this sounds like a stupid question, but how would i output/show the max number?

Comment: try select max(point) as maxnumber from TABLE_A. and then try to output using maxnumber.

Comment: got it thanks, and how would I do it if I wasted to output the second Max number in the column?

Comment: you need to change your sql query accordingly.                                   select max(point) as secondmax from TABLE_A where point<(select max(point from TABLE_A)

Comment: If you select an aggregate in your query, you have to give it alias so that you can reference it with your ColdFusion code.

Comment: You _should_ alias formulas, but you don't _have_ to - it'll generally get auto-aliased to `col1` or similar (depending on db).

Answer (score 0):

you can do like below

```
select max(points) from TABLE_A
```

for getting second max number you can do like below

```
select max(point) as secondmax from TABLE_A where point<(select max(point) from TABLE_A)
```